# Sencha Architect code inside element properties

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

Is it possible to write code inside a property of a certain element? Example label text property. Instead of setting the text to "a+b" setting it to the result of variables a+b.

This is a very simplified example but I am only wondering if something like this can be done in Sencha Architect?

Answer (score -1):

You can override the method you want using this code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.ComponentToOverride, {
    methodToVerride: function(params) {
        // your code
    }
});
```